# asynctask setRequestMethod to post not working

Tags: android, post, android-asynctask, httpconnection

I am trying to make a POST request in an AsyncTask, but the request method stays as GET all the time.

I have this issue since I moved the HTTP request to AsyncTask, the same code worked before, when it was in the UI thread.

The doInBackground code is below:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... string) {

        httpPostToArduino (string[0]);


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute ();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute (s);
    }

    public void httpPostToArduino(String message){

        curArd1UrlString="http://myprivateurl.com";
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL (curArd1UrlString);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder (); //test

        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection ();

            //Set header content
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization","password");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            //Set body content
            OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter (urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            os.write(message.toString ());
            os.flush();

            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream (urlConnection.getInputStream ());

            reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (in));

            //Read the first line of the response - just the JSON
            result.append (reader.readLine ());

            //The below WHILE reads all the content of the response message, but we only need the first line

            String ReceivedJSON = result.toString ();

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject (ReceivedJSON);
```

In the debugger, under urlConnection, for method field, it is always GET. Below a snip from debugger mode, to be clearer.

[image: snip]

I get a response after each request, but the response depends on the body content of the POST request.

What should I change in the code in order to change the request method to POST?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem, for me it happened, because I did not specify the full URL path.

There are two ways to fix this. The first way is to specify the `full url` (with `file.php` at the end) and the second way is to `rewrite` the url in the web server config.

I fixed it by `rewriting` the url in my web server. This is for `nginx`.

This adds .php to the end of the requested URL.

```
location /api {
                rewrite ^(/api/.*)/(\w+) $1/$2.php last;
        }
```

For example you have the Url http://example.com/api/v1/file . After specifying the rewrite this url will be rewritten to http://www.example.com/api/v1/file.php